# What's "hibernate.current_session_context_class" default value?

Tags: hibernate, properties

I can't find anything in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#architecture-current-session). It is stated in this other [site](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2384980), that the default value is `thread`, but the page is very old, plus, it's not official.

Answer (score 0):

There is none - here is a snippet from [the official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/architecture.html#architecture-current-session):

> The hibernate.current_session_context_class configuration parameter defines which org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext implementation should be used. For backwards compatibility, **if this configuration parameter is not set but a org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup is configured, Hibernate will use the org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext**. Typically, the value of this parameter would just name the implementation class to use. For the three out-of-the-box implementations, however, there are three corresponding short names: "jta", "thread", and "managed".